# object name "testUI" is not unique

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, maya

On executing this code below, the window is created on first instance of running the code.  The problem occurs if I try to edit the method createCustomUI....

I get the following error

## Error: line 1: Object's name 'testUI' is not unique.

....and the window is not created. Am trying to work out why this error woule occur and find a good solution to this.

```
import pymel.core as pm

from functools import partial


class ControlCurveTools_UI(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.windowName = "testUI"
        self.windowHeight = 1000
        self.windowWidth = 250

        self.createUI(self.windowName, self.windowHeight, self.windowWidth, True, False)

    def createUI(self, windowName, windowHeight, windowWidth, dock, scroll):

        if dock == True:

            if pm.dockControl(windowName + "_dock", exists = True):
                pm.deleteUI(windowName + "_dock")
        else:

            if pm.window(windowName, exists = True):
                pm.deleteUI(windowName)

        print "here"
        print self.windowName

        self.window = pm.window(windowName, title = windowName, w = windowWidth, h = windowHeight, mnb = False, mxb = False)

        print "here2"
        self.mainlayout = pm.columnLayout(adj = True)

        # Uniqe UI stuff
        self.createCustomUI()

        print "here3"       


        if dock == True:
            pm.dockControl(windowName + "_dock", label = windowName + "_dock", area = "left", content  = self.window, w = self.windowWidth)

        else:   
            pm.showWindow(self.window)


    def createCustomUI(self):

        pm.rowColumnLayout(nc = 1, parent = self.mainlayout, w = self.windowWidth, e=1)

        pm.button(label = "Replace Curve With Selected", p=self.mainlayout)
        pm.button(label = "Mirror Selected Curve", p=self.mainlayout)

        # print "creatingCustomUI"
```

Comment: Searhc for "Object's name  is not unique" and there are lots of hits. Research that and if that doesn't help, [edit] this question and tell us what you did.

Answer (score 2):

You call your build method with dock=True so this section:

```
    if dock == True:
        if pm.dockControl(windowName + "_dock", exists = True):
            pm.deleteUI(windowName + "_dock")
    else:
        if pm.window(windowName, exists = True):
            pm.deleteUI(windowName)
```

does not delete the window because the else statement is not executed.